# Rename 2 files from c# ftp

Tags: c#, ftp

```
        FtpWebRequest ftpWeb;
        FtpWebResponse r;
        string uri;
        uri="ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/filedirectory/" + file_name;
        ftpWeb = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        ftpWeb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "pwd");

        ftpWeb.RenameTo = file_name.Replace("file_name", "rename_file");
        ftpWeb.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;

        r = (FtpWebResponse)ftpWeb.GetResponse();

        uri = "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/filedirectory/" + file_name2;
        ftpWeb = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        ftpWeb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "pwd");

        ftpWeb.RenameTo = file_name2.Replace("file_name2", "rename_file2");
        ftpWeb.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;

        r = (FtpWebResponse)ftpWeb.GetResponse(); // here is error
```

First file is success to rename, but second file is fail...
How to solve this problem? Help me..

this is my code. error code is 500.

Comment: This is a problem with the server not the client. unless you have a really weird file name

Comment: Can you rename the file using any (GUI) FTP client?

Comment: if you have more than one files to rename, use a `foreach` loop and inside the loop, try initializing the `FtpWebRequest` within a `using` block and invoke `GetResponse` within the `using` block.